# get TinyMCE editor text using Java Script

Tags: asp.net

I am using TinyMCE editor in my project. I want to Editors value using Javascript.
I have searched on google and got below code:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()

tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent();
```

While using this code I am getting the following error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getContent' of undefined or null reference
```

I also tried the following to display value in Span (PrevBCC), but value is blank.

```
$("#PrevBCC").text($("#<%= Editor1.ClientID %>").val())
```

Comment: I fired the JS code below in the JavaScript console of Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i) in the http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php demo page of TinyMCE and verified that it works as expected:

tinymce.get("content").getContent();

The "content" string is the ID of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I fired the JS code below in the JavaScript console of Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i) in the http://tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php demo page of TinyMCE and verified that it works as expected:

```
tinymce.get("content").getContent();
```

The "content" string is the ID of the editor.